# To create a rails model, or not to create a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

So lets say I have a model named "Cookies".

Every Cookie has a:
`name, description, color, topping, degrees, food_type, form`

```
VALUES AVAILABLE:
color      [red, blue, orange]
topping    [chocolate, strawberry, vanilla, .. etc] 
degrees    [100, 150, 180, 250]
food_type  [dinner, breakfast, desert]
form       [square, circle, triangle, hexagon]
```

In one of my views I'm going to list all my cookies and the user will be able to filter them by all these values.

They can choose to only show triangle cookies, or only square cookies that you eat for dinner, or maybe a red cookie with vanilla topping for desert.

So my question is. When should I create a model for these values?
Topping might be a easy choice, since I probably want to be able to add new toppings later. But the form and food_type will most likely never change.

```
#Cookies
belong_to color
belong_to topping
belong_to form
name :string
color_id :reference
topping_id :reference
form_id :reference

#Color #Topping and #Form
has_many cookies
name: string
```

As you can see I would have many models that don't do much but have a list of the names of a single attribute of the cookie.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When should I create a model for these values?

I'm sure there are more situations that call for a model/db but here are a few I live by ...

- If your data sets ever need to be changed by a user
- You see yourself changing the data sets quite often
- Your data-sets become large and hard to manage or too complex for the naked eye to make sense of it at a glance
- You need to filter the data sets by certain attributes

Since you say ...

> I'm going to list all my cookies and the user will be able to filter them by all these values.

Then because of the need to filter **I would suggest you make a model because using active record and changing the queries based upon certain attributes is what db's are meant to do**.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute named 'status' to represent the cookie is accomplished or in_doing.
I think you can create model firstly, then update it status and the related attributes